# PHP date and time

Tags: php, database, joomla

I have a Joomla 3 site and use this code to pull data from database

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('receive_date'));
$query->select($db->quoteName('total_amount'));
$query->select($db->quoteName('source'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

?>
<table>
<?php
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $result->receive_date . "</td>" . "<td>" . $result->total_amount . "руб." . "</td>" . "<td>" . $result->source . "</td>" . "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

It returns me for receive_date the date in '2013-09-30 17:49:00' format. Can I remove the time and have only 2013-09-30 for this field?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this link ,
it explains all formats ,
    [Working with dates in Joomla!](http://webamoeba.co.uk/blog/working-with-dates-in-joomla/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `JFactory` class provided by Joomla, you could use this:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . JFactory::getDate($result->receive_date)->format('Y-m-d') ."</td></tr>";
```

In addition to this answer, I thought I would let you know that you don't need to use 3 different `select` attempts in your query, so you can change this:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('receive_date'));
$query->select($db->quoteName('total_amount'));
$query->select($db->quoteName('source'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));
```

to this:

```
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('receive_date'), $db->quoteName('total_amount'), $db->quoteName('source')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$oDate = new DateTime($result->receive_date);
echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: sorry, but I cannot put it into my code, it gives me same date for all my items because of foreach, I am not good at php

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this... The **`OOP`** way..!

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$yourdate); 
echo $mysqlformat=$date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the following:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->receive_date));
```